# Scheme: solving task WITHOUT using if/cond?

Tags: scheme, racket

So I've gotten rather simple task, in theory.

"Create a procedure where you take an integer as a parameter. If the integer is 0, return 0. If the integer is less than 0, return -1. If the integer is more than 0, return 1.

Solve this task **without** using if/cond(the only special forms allowed, are *define*, *and*, *or*)."

A very unpractical task, but a requirement for my course nonetheless. I've been stuck with this task for hours now, so I'd love some input!

Keep in mind that the procedure **must** return -1, 0 or 1. #t or #f are not good enough.

Answer (score 6):

Both `and` and `or` are special versions of `if`. Eg.

```
(and a b)           ; is the same as
(if a b #f)

(and a b c ...)         ; is the same as
(if a (and b c ...) #f)

(or a b)    ; is the same as
(if a
    a       ; though a is only evaluated once!
    b)

(or a b c ...)  ; is the same as
(if a
    a           ; though a is only evaluated once!
    (or b c ...))
```

Notice that for 3 or more elements the result has `and` or `or` in it. You just apply the same transformation until you have something with just `if`.

If you want something like:

```
(if a 'x 'y)
```

You see that its obviously `(or (and a 'x) 'y)` since it turns into

```
(if (if a 'x #f)
    (if a 'x #f)
    'y)
```

Know that every value except `#f` is considered a true value. The basic method of doing this in "reverse" is knowing how `and` and `or` short circuits like `if`. If you need a special value returned instead of the result of a predicate you use and:

```
(and (null? x) 'empty-result)
```

If you need a false value to continue logic you use `or`

```
(or (and (null? x) 'empty-result)
    (and (pair? x) 'pair-result))
```

If you need a default and have a `or` you just add it.

```
(or (and (null? x) 'empty-result)
    (and (pair? x) 'pair-result)
    'default-result)
```

If you happen to have `and` in the outer you need to wrap an `or` to get the default-result:

```
(or (and ...)
    'default-result)
```

Good luck!

Comment: `positive-result`? Are you sure you didn't mean `empty-result` or `null-result` or similar? ;-)

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young Actually every result except the `default-result` are positive results since they satisfied the predicate, but I didn't want to have `'positive-result` on both terms. I see it might be confusing so i followed your advice :-)

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty simple implementation:

```
(define (signum n)
  (or (and (zero? n) 0)
      (and (positive? n) 1)
      (and (negative? n) -1)))
```

Edit: I wrote my answer before I read Sylwester's post, but you should definitely read it for the theory of how this construction works.